How can i achieve the same curve of the face in the 3D model as the one in the 2D image?
New to 3D and have been struggling to match this model, i cant find any tutorials on how to achieve this specific shape/curve. My issue is that on the 2D image the bend goes all the way down. Whereas the 3D one does not since the bevel goes only towards the half way mark,which results in a straight sort of edge after the half, atleast from what i can tell. What i need is to basically have the same shape xD please somebody help me out.
Please focus only on the curve of the face, ignore the backfaces on the 2D image they are were purely for perspective,



Do the same on the other side?

i mean the actual shape of the face, as in the curve in the 3D model isnt the same as the 2D image

I think I understand now... add extra loops and fine tune them by grabbing
